# How can I declare that a parameter IS a type and not and instance of type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Given

```
Class X{
}
```

I want to pass the class as a parameter like:

```
someMethod(theType: ?X?){
   theType.staticMethod //or
   new theType();
}
```

Are construct signatures (interfaces) my only option here?

I can probably use a construct signature but it feels unnatural and the construct signature doesn't really seem to convey the specific type that can be new'd up.  I could be missing some detail I suppose.  Here is a more detailed example but with generics which are not runtime types.

```
abstract class GreeterBase<T extends GreeterBase<T>>{
    message:string;

    constructor(message:string){
        this.message=message;
    }

    public static create<T>(message:string):T{
        //This is the only part that doesn't work.
        return new T(message);  //This doesn't work.
    }

    public abstract greet():string;

    public logMessage(){
        console.log(this.message);
    }

}

class EnglishGreeter extends GreeterBase<EnglishGreeter>{
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.message;
    }
}

class FriendlyMessager<T extends GreeterBase<T>>{

    private _myGreeter:T;

    constructor(andSoForth:string){
        this._myGreeter = GreeterBase.create<T>(andSoForth);
        this._myGreeter.logMessage();
    }

    public sendGreeting(){
        this._myGreeter.greet();
    }
}

let messager = new FriendlyMessager<EnglishGreeter>(', how are you');
messager.sendGreeting();
```

TS Playground [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20GreeterBase%3CT%20extends%20GreeterBase%3CT%3E%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20message%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(message%3Astring)%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.message%3Dmessage%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20static%20create%3CT%3E(message%3Astring)%3AT%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2FThis%20is%20the%20only%20part%20that%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20T(message)%3B%20%20%2F%2FThis%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20abstract%20greet()%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20logMessage()%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(this.message)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20EnglishGreeter%20extends%20GreeterBase%3CEnglishGreeter%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FriendlyMessager%3CT%20extends%20GreeterBase%3CT%3E%3E%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20_myGreeter%3AT%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(andSoForth%3Astring)%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._myGreeter%20%3D%20GreeterBase.create%3CT%3E(andSoForth)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this._myGreeter.logMessage()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20sendGreeting()%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._myGreeter.greet()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20messager%20%3D%20new%20FriendlyMessager%3CEnglishGreeter%3E('%2C%20how%20are%20you')%3B%0D%0Amessager.sendGreeting()%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Im not sure what your goal is. May you specify your question? Why would you say new theType if you have new X?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the constructor function as a parameter because the `<T>` in `public static create<T>(message:string)` just helps typescript to deduce type information, which will be lost in js.

```
public static create<T>(message:string, cTor: {new(string): T;}):T{
    //This is the only part that doesn't work.
    return new cTor(message);  //This doesn't work.
}
```

I think you should redesign you classes. Maybe [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20GreeterBase%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20message%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(message%3Astring)%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.message%3Dmessage%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20static%20create%3CT%20extends%20GreeterBase%3E(message%3Astring%2C%20cTor%3A%20%7Bnew(string)%3A%20T%3B%7D)%3AT%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2FThis%20is%20the%20only%20part%20that%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20cTor(message)%3B%20%20%2F%2FThis%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20abstract%20greet()%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20logMessage()%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(this.message)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20EnglishGreeter%20extends%20GreeterBase%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FriendlyMessager%3CT%20extends%20GreeterBase%3E%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20_myGreeter%3AT%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(andSoForth%3Astring)%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._myGreeter%20%3D%20GreeterBase.create(andSoForth%2C%20T)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this._myGreeter.logMessage()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20sendGreeting()%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._myGreeter.greet()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20messager%20%3D%20new%20FriendlyMessager%3CEnglishGreeter%3E('%2C%20how%20are%20you')%3B%0D%0Amessager.sendGreeting()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20greeter%20%3D%20GreeterBase.create(%22English%22%2C%20EnglishGreeter)%3B%0D%0Agreeter.logMessage()%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `typeof` type operator to get the type of a particular value (in your case, `X`):

```
someMethod(myCtor: typeof X) {
   let f: X = new myCtor(); // OK
}
```

Comment: I want theType to be passed in. Here X is static.  I'll update my question with more detail.

Comment: So 
    let X = function SomeType(){
     
    };
    
    class MyClass{
      someMethod(myCtor: typeof X) {
       let f: X = new myCtor(); // OK
      }
    }
Does not work.